# The code isn't efficient

Tags: c, algorithm

This is a code for problem 12 in ProjectEuler.It gives the correct output as 76576500. But it took long time to give the output. Can you help me to get more efficient code for this? Thank you in comments.
https://projecteuler.net/problem=12

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

main(){
    bool flag= true;
    int triangular_n , divisor , count , remainder , counter;
    triangular_n=1;
    counter = 2;
    while(flag){
            count = 0;
            divisor = 2;
            while(divisor<triangular_n){
                    remainder = triangular_n%divisor;
                    if(remainder==0){
                            count++;

                    }
                    divisor++;
            }
            if(count==499){
                    break;
            }
            triangular_n += counter;
            counter++;
            printf("%d\n",triangular_n);
    }

    printf("%d\n", triangular_n);

}
```

~

Comment: This is more suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question could be suitable for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help), as long as (a) your code works as intended, (b) your code is real code, rather than example code, and (c) your code is included in the body of the question. If you wish for a peer review to improve all aspects of your code, please post it on Code Review and delete your question here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: No, do not delete the question here! Deleting too many questions as a new user will get you in trouble and count towards a site ban. The question is on-topic for SO. Just keep the code review site in mind next time you have a similar question.

Comment: @samgak Can you prove that the number of divisors of triangle numbers is an increasing sequence?

Comment: @samgak Nevermind, it's not: `#divisors(9*10/2)=|{1,3,9,10,15,45}|=6>#divisors(10*11/2)=|{1,5,11,55}|=4` Binary search won't work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few tricks you can use to speed this up.

The `n`th triangle number is `n*(n+1)/2`.

For all integers `n`, `n` and `n+1` are co-prime. This means that the number of divisors of `n*(n+1)` is the number of divisors `n` multiplied by the number of divisors of `n+1`.

For an even number `k`, the number of divisors of `k/2` is half the number of divisors of `k`.

So, to compute the number of divisors of the `n`th triangle number, count the divisors of `n+1`, multiply with the number of divisors of `n` that you have from the previous step, and divide by two.